# List all directories and files recursively from FTP site

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, wget, lftp

I am looking to spider an FTP directory and all inclusive sub-directories and files and write the information to a file.

I tried using lftp, but I noticed the site does not support `lftp> ls -1R > rammb.txt`
so now I am trying to figure out the best route. I would like to include the date as far as information sent to the file.

Previously, what I tried was `lftp> find -d 10 > rammb.txt`
but it did not provide the dates of the files. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use `find --ls`, it will output full file information. The option is available since lftp version 4.4.12.